# Why my service is not starting?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a Jar that contain only this :

```
com/something/services/myService.java
```

then i try to start the service from inside my app (who include the jar) like this :

```
intent.setClassName("com.something.services","com.something.services.myService");
myActivity.startService(intent);
```

but the onStartCommand of my service is never fired :(

the code of the services :

```
package com.something.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class myService extends Service {

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("myService", "onStartCommand");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

What did i miss ?

Answer (score 1):

You may forgot to register the service in you Manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Without log it's hard to find answer, so you can check 2 things,

1. Did you register your service in Manifest file
2. And check spelling for your package name and service class name.